# Disable button with validation Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fr-preference').validation({
            txtdiningOthers: {
                name: 'OtherDiningPreference'
            },
        });
      Profile.init()
      $(document).on("click", "#btnUpdatePreference", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#frPreferenceId").attr("action"),
                    type: "POST",
                    ...
            });

    };
```

And:

```
txtdiningOthers: {
            name: 'OtherDiningPreference',
            rule: {
                onlyText: false,
                maxlength: 39
            },
            message: mgsRequiredMaxLength
        },
```

I want to disable button Update Preference when text box more than 39 chars, can not send request when i click button Update.

Comment: Please create a working code snippet of your html/js so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).on("click", "#btnUpdatePreference", function () {
    if(!$('.fr-preference').valid()){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $("#frPreferenceId").attr("action"),
                        type: "POST",
                        ...
                });
    }else{
 //your button disable statement;
}
    });
```

Before calling ajax function check whether `.fr-preference` vaalidation is valid aren't based on that you can allow ajax call.

Comment: when you give maxLength property to your textBox in html . Then it will not allow the user to type anything after your mentioned length.   For safety purpose if you want to validate then manually use blur function and manually validate and disable the button

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: $('[name = "OtherDiningPreference"]').on('blur keyup', function() {
    if($('.fr-preference').valid()){
        $('#btnUpdatePreference').prop('disabled', false);  
    } else {
        $('#btnUpdatePreference').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

Comment: if(!$('.fr-preference').valid()) { return} else $.ajax

Comment: anyway, tks you so much to help me!

Comment: welcome. If the proposed solution resolves your issue then you can upvote the answer.